# Как сохранить таймер что-бы он не сбрасывался при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline="January 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300"; //for Ukraine
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // for endless timer
initializeClock('countdown', deadline);
```

```html
<h1 class="countdown-title">Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="countdown" class="countdown">
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="days countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">Days</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="hours countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">Hours</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="minutes countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">Minutes</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="seconds countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">Seconds</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не [ответ на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473957/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)?

Comment: нет мне нужно под мой

Comment: Тогда у вас есть уникальный шанс - прочесть тот код, и переделать его "под ваш". Это не тот сайт где вам дадут готовое решение любой проблемы, тут принято подсказывать как а не делать всё за автора вопроса :)

Comment: Это тот сайт где могут дать готовое решение, благодарю таких людей от души + если обьясняют как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы сохранить таймер при перезагрузке страницы, необходимо хранить дату и время, до которого отсчитывается таймер, в локальном хранилище браузера. Это можно сделать, используя методы localStorage.setItem() и localStorage.getItem().

Например, в функции initializeClock() можно добавить следующий код:

```
// Получаем дату и время до которого отсчитывается таймер из локального хранилища
var savedDeadline = localStorage.getItem('deadline');
if (savedDeadline) {
  deadline = new Date(savedDeadline);
}

// Сохраняем дату и время до которого отсчитывается таймер в локальном хранилище
localStorage.setItem('deadline', deadline);
```

На точно такой же вопрос я уже отвечал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473957/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Comment: Дубликаты не сильно помогают сайту пополнять базу знаний, и практически бесполезны для тех кому нужны знания а не готовый код, сейчас вы написали автору решение стилизованное под его код и теперь на сайте два абсолютно одинаковых решения одной проблемы, которые только выглядят как разные и могут ввести в заблуждение новичков.

Comment: я добавил в конце скрипта и не рабоатет